# CoffeScript binding variables

Tags: javascript, variables, binding, coffeescript

I have a class

```
class window.MapHandler
  map = null
  userLocationMarker = null

  makeMap: (location) ->
    myOptions =
      zoom: 14
      center: location
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    @map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions)
  placeMarker: (location, icon_path) ->
    if icon_path
      markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon_path, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25, 25))
    else
      markerImage = null
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      position: location
      map: @map
      icon: markerImage)

  defineUserLocation: () ->
    if navigator.geolocation
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) =>
          pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            map: @map
            position: pos
            content: 'Если это не ваше местоположение - передвиньте маркер'
          )
          @map.setCenter(pos)
          @userLocationMarker = @placeMarker(pos, null)
      )
    alert @userLocationMarker.getPosition()
```

Why in the end of all I have a centered map and maker in this point, but @userLocationMarker is undefined and getPosition method call error?

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an async function. Its callback (where you set `@userLocationMarker`) runs after your `alert` call. You could e.g. put your `alert` line into the callback, too.

Comment: But i have userLocationMarker = null in the top of class

Comment: @koshak1993: Ah, that needs to be `userLocationMarker: null`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why (position) function see variable map, but don't see userLocationMarker

Comment: When you write `userLocationMarker =`, you're defining a variable with that name that lives only in the function body created by `class Window.MapHandler`—a private variable. Using `:` instead makes it a property of the class's prototype.

Comment: The reason `@map` is visible is that you wrote `@map = ...` elsewhere. `@map` has nothing to do with your `map = ` declaration. You see?